# Retrieve specific rows in subquery which caused "Single-Row Subquery Returns More than One Row"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query where a nested subquery throws the error "Single-Row Subquery Returns More Than One Row." This error happens in one env. (TEST) but not another (STAGE) due to some data differences.

I need to find out exactly which data is causing this. But how to rewrite this as a WHERE/HAVING COUNT > 0 query? The subquery is nested.

Suppose `PLANS_T.MANAGER_ID` is the "outer" value I'm checking in the `PERSON_T` subquery below.

```
select * from plans_t p 
where 
(select inactive_date 
from persons.person_t 
where 
current_flag = 'Y' and 
uniqueidentifier = p.manager_id
) is null
```

This is in Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select inactive_date 
from persons.person_t 
where 
current_flag = 'Y' and 
uniqueidentifier in (select p.manager_id from plans_t p)
group by inactive_date 
having count(*)>1
```

Comment: Thanks. I also got some more info other than `inactive_date` (I actually needed the `personId`, an identifier of some kind) but this worked and I got my info!!